# Switching between giu and cli on 14.04 server

Tags: server, interface

I have a 14.04 test server I am running in vmware. I installed a gui (sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop) that a starts by typing startx. Now I am wondering how to switch back to the cli without rebooting

Comment: CTRL-ALT-F1 will bring you to a terminal screen, (X will still be running in the background and you can switch back to the GUI with CTRL-ALT-F7) - Provided of course vmware isn't capturing those key combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the logout option (at the bottom of the main menu) - not shutdown or restart.